# Why does not work pandas df.loc + lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I have created pandas frame from csv file.
And I want to select rows use lambda.
But it does not work.
I use [this pandas manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable).
[image]
exception: 
[image]

what is problem?
thanks.

Comment: this is brand new in 0.18.1, make sure you are using the correct version.

Answer (score 7):

As @BrenBam has said in the comment this syntax was added in 0.18.1 and it won't work in previous versions.

Selection By Callable:

> .loc, .iloc, .ix and also [] indexing can accept a callable as
>   indexer. The callable must be a function with one argument (the
>   calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that returns valid output for
>   indexing.

Example (version 0.18.1):

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  2  4
2  3  4  0
3  0  2  3
4  3  0  4

In [11]: df.loc[lambda df: df.a == 3]
Out[11]:
   a  b  c
2  3  4  0
4  3  0  4
```

For versions <= 0.18.0 you can't use `Selection by callable`:

do it this way instead:

```
df.loc[df['Date'] == '2003-01-01 00:00:00', ['Date']]
```

Comment: thanks, but I use this post [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable)  and I can not  understand why it not woking in mine ..

Comment: @DenisOgr: What version of pandas are you using?  As it says on that page, that feature was added in 0.18.1.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks, I use 0.16.0 and it feature "New in version 0.18.1."